# How many users got the X badge before I did?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

Is it possible to know how many users got the X badge before me? I have a gold badge and I would like to know how many times it was awarded before I got it.

Do you also think this is an interesting feature to have on the BADGES tab?

Meanwhile, maybe someone skilled in database could write a query for this on [stackexchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries), assuming that there is enough information on the DB right now to make this possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero?userid=176769

Comment: I would rather if I didn't have to do a manual count of how many users got the badge before me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a query on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer for this kind of information:

- https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/446048/order-of-user-being-awarded-badge

You were the 355<sup>th</sup> user to receive the Unsung Hero gold badge:

- https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/446048/order-of-user-being-awarded-badge?BadgeName=Unsung+Hero&BadgeClass=1&UserId=176769

Answer (score 6):

Just to show the far reach of the SO API.

In Mathematica:

```
getPosBadge[userID_, badge_] := 
 Module[{totalusers, a, stat}, 

  stat = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/badges/";

  totalusers = "total" /. Import[stat <> badge <> "?pagesize=1&page=1", "JSON"];

  a = Join @@ Table[("users" /. 
       Import[stat <> badge <> "?pagesize=100&page=" <> ToString[page], "JSON"]), 
             {page, 1, Ceiling[totalusers/100]}];

  totalusers - Position["display_name" /. a, userID] + 1] 

getPosBadge["karlphillip", "226"]

-> 357
```

Comment: I'm a bit slow today, I didn't get what Mathematica has to do with this. And thank you very much.

Comment: Mathematica has nohing to do with it. 357 does

Comment: I get that, that's why I upvoted. But leaving a lost reference on your answer is no good. Do you work with them or something?

Comment: @karlp NOOOO It's just a convoluted way to invoke an API. Removing reference!

Comment: Humm, Ok. I understood it now. When you said "the far reach of an API" I was lost, but now I see that you meant "the far reach of the SO API". Thank you, sir.

Comment: @karlp Edited. My English is not as good as it should be :(

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero?userid=176769) list recipients in reverse order.

By counting from your id ([on page 9](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/226?page=9)) to the end of page 15, I get 116 others who got the `Unsung Hero` badge before you.

Comment: Thank you very much, but that count doesn't sound right. And I do think I'll be able to get more gold badges along the way and I would rather not to do a manual count every time I would like to know that information.

Comment: My manual count says I was user #376, or something near that.

Comment: @karlphillip: I have to ask, why does it matter whether you are user #376 or #673 to get a badge? I mean, I can totally understand the excitement of finding out that you're the *very first* user to get a particular gold badge, but 376th? That piece of data is simply not important enough to always include it for every badge on every user profile ever. Especially since you can still calculate it if you really, really must. (That being said, @yhw42's counting really is way off. (^_^))

Comment: @RegDwight Because it's an interesting information. Why bother calculating how much reputation a user got in a week/month/year and compare it to the rest of the users, just to display on your profile `top 1% this week`. It has no practical use either. **However**, it is interesting to know that.

Comment: @karlphillip: The `top 1% this week` is *extremely* useful. It lets you see, at a glance, whether the user is still active on the site. Being able to see that is something many, many people kept asking for over and over and over again. (I'm at 3k on SO. But I haven't participated at all for a year or so. My rep alone doesn't tell you that. My rep-league percentage does.) On the other hand, if you visited my profile and saw that I was the 14296th user to get a Nice Answer badge, that would tell you so little it could just as well be a randomly generated number.

Comment: My apologies @karl! My Sunday morning math failed me. My manual count was actually #356.